# number format a string inside a var

Tags: jquery

I have this variable `data` which contains a huge HTML code.

Somewhere in it, there are `<td></td>` tags that contains an amount (eg. `<td>1000.00</td>`). I want to format it to English notation, however, I am not sure how to do it since it is a huge string.

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: How you want to format it?

Comment: A simple, 1,000.00 english notation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: The best way i think is to use parseInt("your number here")

Then format it. using jquery plugin

http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you generate in the data string

```
<td class="format-this">1000.00</td>
```

then in jquery,

```
var MyDataToFormat = $("<div></div>").html(data);
```

OR

```
var MyDataToFormat = $("<div />", { html: data }) //thankz for suggesting this
```

now you will get a DOM object.

then use number formatter [Jquery number formatter](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178) like this one to format those classes.

```
$(MyDataToFormat).find('.format-this').each(function() {
    $(this).html($.number($(MyDataToFormat).children('.format-this').html()));
});
```

This will change the html inside the DOM with ure format.
Let me know if this help, haven't test, wrote it raw

sample working, http://jsfiddle.net/q46LC/

Comment: Maybe, better $("<div />", { value: data }) then $("<div></div>").val(data)? Also, further you include already jQuery object into $(MyDataToFormat)

Comment: Sorry mate, i updated the code. Instead of using children, need to use find. Instead of loading with .val, load with .html. Also gave a fiddle sample

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify further? Are you searching specifically for 1000.00 or are you searching for all  tags that have some numeric data within them?

You could probably get away with

```
    $('td').each(function() { //check value here 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for converting to currency format use below function. [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79G9k/)

```
var amount = "1000.00";
alert(toUSD(amount));

function toUSD(number) {
    var number = number.toString(), 
    dollars = number.split('.')[0], 
    cents = (number.split('.')[1] || '') +'00';
    dollars = dollars.split('').reverse().join('')
        .replace(/(\d{3}(?!$))/g, '$1,')
        .split('').reverse().join('');
    return '$' + dollars + '.' + cents.slice(0, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
parseInt("Your number from html");
```

Then use this plugin to format. or just use native.

http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jquery.formatNumber`](https://github.com/RaphaelDDL/jquery.formatNumber) plugin:

> jQuery plugin for formatting numbers, good for currencies. Option to
>   choose the cents and thousands digit. Defaults to US' 9,999.00.

Code:

```
//produces 29,323,894.23 (e.g. US standard)
$('td').formatNumber({
  cents: '.',
  decimal: ','
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E5rWF/

Comment: Problem is, the number is in a variable, not in DOM.

Comment: @LeandroGarcia you can build a jQuery object without affect the DOM, see: http://jsfiddle.net/E5rWF/1/